# List all folders that are in any 3rd subdirectory from current

Tags: vb.net, list, directory, subdirectory

I would need to make an array list, displaying all folders that are in the 3rd subfolder from the current one.

```
Folder1/sub1folder/sub2folder/sub3folder
```

It has to be recursive. what I need is an array of strings that contains all the strings like above. 
I do know how to look recursively into folders, but I do not know how to limit the search to the 3rd subfolder.

Thanks!

Comment: In your recursive procedure, use a parameter for the current depth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my stab at it. I tested it and it works for me:

```
Dim resultList as List(Of String) = DirectorySearch(baseDirectoryPath, 0)

Function DirectorySearch(directoryPath As String, level As Integer) As List(Of String)

    level += 1

    Dim directories As String() = IO.Directory.GetDirectories(directoryPath)

    Dim resultList As New List(Of String)

    If level = 3 Then
        For Each subDirectoryPath In directories
            Dim result As String = GetFinalResult(subDirectoryPath)
            resultList.Add(result)
        Next
    Else
        For Each subDirectoryPath In directories
            Dim partialResultList As List(Of String) = DirectorySearch(subDirectoryPath, level)
            resultList.AddRange(partialResultList)
        Next
    End If

    Return resultList

End Function

Private Function GetFinalResult(directoryPath As String) As String
    Dim directoryInfo As New IO.DirectoryInfo(directoryPath)
    Return String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}/{3}",
                         directoryInfo.Parent.Parent.Parent.Name,
                         directoryInfo.Parent.Parent.Name,
                         directoryInfo.Parent.Name,
                         directoryInfo.Name)
End Function
```

Comment: You are very welcome, I am glad it works for you. Also: if you want to generalize the level depth (currently fixed at 3), you can pass it as a parameter in DirectorySearch and then build GetFinalResult as a function that recursively grabs each directoryInfo.Parent up to the desired level.

Answer (score 1):

If you had a recursive function which began at the current folder:

```
Public Function recurse(Optional depth As Integer = 0) As String()
  Dim folderList As String()
  If (depth < 3) Then
    depth += 1
    folderList = recurse(depth)
  Else
    'Do third subfolder analysis and set the output to folderList
    Return folderList
  End If
End Sub
```